# Cordova geolocation fails before the user accept the dialog

Tags: android, angular, cordova

I am writting an angular app and I use cordova to make a hybrid mobile app. I have a component where I use AGM (angular google maps). I have the map element like this somewhere in the template.

```
<agm-map *ngIf="latitude && longitude">
     ....
</agm-map>
```

In the controller(.ts file) I have this method:

```
private setCurrentLocation() {
 if ('geolocation' in navigator) {
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition((position) => {
    alert("success!")
    this.latitude = position.coords.latitude;
    this.longitude = position.coords.longitude;
  }, (err)=>{
    alert('failed...');
  });
 }
}
```

Which I call here:

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.setCurrentLocation();
}
```

And here is what happens: In the browser is all fine, it asks for the html5 location and if the user accepts it shows the map (since the lon & lat get a value so the *ngIf becomse true in the template).

However when I run the app in the android (via cordova build android), the **FIRST** time the user visits this component 2 things happen: 1) the dialog for location acceptance pops up and 2) the error callback runs instantly, even before the user accepts or decline. Also even if he accepts nothing happens. **BUT** if he accepts, and close the component and visit it again (with location accepted this time, so the dialog will not pop up) it works fine.

Any idea why that happens? Thanks.